# Selection Sort using a pointer and without loops

Tags: c, loops, sorting, pointers, selection-sort

I am trying to use a recursive function to sort an array in ascending order. The catch is I can't use any for, while, or do/while loops. There are plenty of selection sort resources online but I'm having difficulty finding anything without loops and also including a pointer.

A short step-by-step of what I'm trying to do.

1. Place the marker at the first element of the array

2.If the marker is pointing at the last element of the array, then stop. Otherwise continue

3.Find the smallest element to the right of the marker

4.If this element is smaller than the element the marker is pointing at, then swap

5.Advance the marker to the next element to the right

6.Go to step 2

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you can design it using loops, and convert the loops.

Any loop can be converted into the following form:

```c
State state = init();
while (cond(&state))
   body(&state);
tail(&state);
```

And this loop be implemented trivially using recursion.

```c
void recursive(State *state) {
   if (!cond(state))
      return;

   body(state);
   recursive(state);
}

State = state = init();
recursive(&state);
tail(&state);
```

---

That said, it's a lot easier to tackle this problem head on.

Selection sort is trivial to implement using recursion. As a whole, you are repeatedly sorting an ever shrinking portion of the array. After swapping the first element for smallest element, you need to sort the remainder of the array, which can easily be done using a recursive call.

That leaves the loop to find the smallest element of the array. Again, this is trivial to define in terms of itself. The smallest element of a list is the smallest of first element and the smallest element of the remainder of the list.

Comment: Added to my answer.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding exactly how to implement your solution with my problem. Would you mind giving me an example with a small array. Perhaps {5,6,3,1}. Much appreciated.

Comment: An example of selection sort? 1 and 5 are swapped giving {1,6,3,5}. Then you sort the {6,3,5}. 3 and 6 are swapped giving {3,6,5}. Then you sort {6,5}. 5 and 6 are swapped giving {5,6}. Then you sort {6}. Done.